# How to write command find with variable in terminal

Tags: variables, terminal, find, command

I would like to run the find command from a variable like below:

```
$myFind = "/Volumes/WORKSPACE/MyProject/ -name '*.html' ! -name 'MyFile.html'"

$find $myFind
```

However it seem doest work. How can i execute the find with variable ?

Please assit.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the white spaces before and after '='.

I tried this and worked perfect. If you still have errors please let me know.

Code:

```
myFind="/Volumes/WORKSPACE/MyProject/ -name *.html ! -name MyFile.html"
find $myFind
```

Comment: This might work here if your working directory doesn't contain any .html files, but should fail otherwise (since `*` will just act like the literal * character, if there are no html files in the working directory). Using an array would solve the problem. See [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time) for more info.